# is not recognised as an OLE file PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Estoy intentando leer un fichero xls que subo, pero me da el siguiente error

```
is not recognised as an OLE file
```

Estos son los datos que recibo

```
[
 'mes' => '05/2020',
 'fichero' => [
    'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpZecPC4',
    'error' => (int) 0,
    'name' => 'ASISTENCIA-MAYO 2020.xls',
    'type' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'size' => (int) 951628
 ]
]
```

Y asi trato el fichero que subo

```
$archivo = $this->request->getData()['fichero'];

        move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'files/horarios' . DS . $archivo['name']);

        $inputFileType = 'Xls';

        $inputFileName = WWW_ROOT . 'files/horarios' . DS . $archivo['name'];

        $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();

        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);

        $titulo = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getTitle();
```

Pero me salta este error de is not recognised as an OLE file, no se si es por el type del fichero lo que falla pero el archivo que guardo es xls

Answer (score 0):

## Prueba otro formato

Desconozco todas las implicaciones de tu caso, pero en mi experiencia con ese mensaje de error fue que apesar de tener mi archivo guardado con el formato Xls, persistia en ser un formato Html asi que solo cambie el formato de lectura de:

`$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();`

a Html()

`$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html();`

Pudiera ser tambien algo como CSV pero para eso tendrias  que definir delimitadores y otras propiedades que no he probado pero si leido al respecto.